# layout not being called, no errors or exceptions

Tags: xml, magento, config

Magento is displaying the page of my modules, but only the header, footer and sidebars. The content of my page is not being displayed. After lots of checking and re-checking I cannot see anything wrong with my files but it seems the layout file is not being called.

Echoing directly from my control returns expected result

Echoing directly from my block **DOES NOT** return any result

Breaking the layout.xml returns no exceptions.

Breaking the config.xml returns a 404 and an error in system.log

`var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());` shows the following

```
array
0 => string 'default' (length=7)
1 => string 'STORE_default' (length=13)
2 => string 'THEME_frontend_default_default' (length=30)
3 => string 'prefs_index_signup' (length=18)
4 => string 'customer_logged_in' (length=18)
```

this module had previously worked and I cannot work out what has been changed. I have also compared my current code with code I have in a repo on git but there seems to be no difference, Obviously something has changed, what else can I check for?

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/ps_prefs/prefs.xml

```
<layout>  
<prefs_index_signup>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="prefs/signup" name="prefs_new" template="ps/prefs/new.phtml" />
    </reference>
</prefs_index_signup>
</layout>
```

app/code/local/Ps/Prefs/Block/Signup.php

```
class Ps_Prefs_Block_Signup
extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public $key;
public $locale;

public function _construct()
{
    $this->setKey();
    $this->getLocale();
}
```

app/code/local/Ps/Prefs/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<global>
    <models>
        <prefs>
            <class>Ps_Prefs_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>prefs_resource</resourceModel>
        </prefs>

        <prefs_resource>
            ....resources.....
        </prefs_resource>
    </models>
        <blocks>
        <prefs>
            <class>Ps_Prefs_Block</class>
        </prefs>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <prefs>
                <file>ps_prefs/prefs.xml</file>
            </prefs>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
        <prefs>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ps_Prefs</module>
                <frontName>prefs</frontName>
            </args>
        </prefs>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Ps/Prefs/controllers/IndexController

```
 class Ps_Prefs_IndexController
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function signupAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: check in other module's config.xml if the `<prefs>` tag isn't used for a layout update, it can happen when CTRL+C/CTRL+V

Comment: WOW! after all that! thanks @OSdave

Answer (score 0):

from above xml looks like you have not mentioned reference root.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

As well try to render layout from like below, i m using same in my page and it is working.

```
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();
```

Hope this will help you.

Cheers!